# if $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a^2_{n}-2a_{n}+2}-1$, show that there exists a constant $c$ such $a_{2n}<c<a_{2n+1}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$,such $a_{1}=1$,and 
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a^2_{n}-2a_{n}+2}-1$$

prove or disprove :there exists a constant $c$ such
$$a_{2n}<c<a_{2n+1}?$$

my idea: since
$$a_{n+1}+1=\sqrt{(a_{n}-1)^2+1}$$
so
$$(a_{n+1}+1)^2=(a_{n}-1)^2+1$$
then I can't it. Thank you

**By the way** this problem seems the form is simple, but when I try solve this problem, I fell is very hard.

Comment: I would try showing that $a_{2n}$ is increasing and $a_{2n+1}$ is decreasing. I dont know if it works, but its the first step.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the function $f\colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ given by $f(x)= \sqrt{(1-x)^2+1}-1$. $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$, with

$$f'(x) = \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{(1-x)^2+1}} < 0,$$

except for $x = 1$, where the derivative is zero. So $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,1]$, and has a unique fixed point $c = \frac{1}{4}$. Since $f$ is strictly decreasing, we have

$$f(x) < c \iff x > c,$$

and vice versa. Since $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ and $a_1 = 1 > c$, we have indeed

$$a_{2n} < c < a_{2n+1}$$

for all $n$.

Since $\lvert f'\left(x\right)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, $f$ is a contraction, so the sequence converges to the fixed point, and the subsequence $(a_{2n})$ is strictly increasing, while $(a_{2n+1})$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Oh,My god,I forgot this try!Nice,Thank you +1